# Dropping a table/column automatically drops views using it - how to warn instead?

Tags: db2, view, drop-table, db2-midrange

If I have a view that uses a column, and I remove that column/table, the view is dropped automatically.

Is there a setting I can change such that it instead prevents the removal of the column/table, warning that it has dependencies?

Operation System: I5 or IBM i

Operating System Version: V7R1M0

> [From comment] The view is not dropped; it may be marked as invalid.

```
SELECT * FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES
WHERE SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MYLIB' and table_name = 'MYVIEW';
--returns 1 row

ALTER TABLE MYLIB.MYTABLE DROP COLUMN TEST2;

SELECT * FROM QSYS2.SYSTABLES
WHERE SYSTEM_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MYLIB' and table_name = 'MYVIEW';
--returns 0 rows
```

...That looks to me like it was dropped?

Comment: Insufficient information. EDIT your question to add the Db2-server operating system (z/OS, i-Series, Linux/Unix/Windows)  and the Db2-version.

Comment: @mao Sorry, edited.

Comment: @mustaccio Looks to me like it was dropped. If it's invalid, where can I find it? I would've expected it to still be in QSYS2.SYSTABLES.

Answer (score 1):

For i-series, at least for 7.1, you can try the RESTRICT clause of DROP COLUMN.

There is also a RESTRICT clause for DROP TABLE.

Per [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzdropst.htm)

> RESTRICT
>
> Specifies that the column cannot be dropped if any views, indexes, triggers, or constraints are dependent on the column. 1
>
> If all the columns referenced in a constraint are dropped in the same ALTER TABLE statement, RESTRICT does not prevent the drop.

Comment: Hmm. Problem with this is it requires the developer to remember to add the command every time. I also don't know how to modify System i Navigator to add the RESTRICT clause... that's probably a separate Question, though.